# rdoc2.2 file not found error during make of openwsman 2.4.12 (and 2.4.10)

Tags: ruby, rdoc, openwsman

I'm trying to compile openwsman 2.4.12 (and 2.4.10) on a CentOS 7 system and am running into the error below. I've also duplicated the error on a RHEL 7 system as well and don't know what to make of it. It seems to be erroring on rdoc and trying to reference version 2.2, but I'm running 4.2.0 of rdoc. I am however running ruby 2.2.0, so not sure it its thinking it should be looking for 2.2 of rdoc because of the version of ruby I have, though both are the latest versions available. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. It is worth mentioning that this worked on a RHEL 6.5 box.

```
Creating rdoc documentation .../bin/sh: ./rdoc2.2: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [bindings/ruby/html] Error 127
make[1]: *** [bindings/ruby/CMakeFiles/ruby_gem.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

These are the results of the cmake command I ran.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Version 2.4.12
-- Package Version "2.4"
-- Plugin API Version "2.2"
-- Package build timestamp 201501122347
-- Building for x86_64
-- Libraries will be installed in /usr/lib64
-- Configuration will be installed in /etc/openwsman
-- building PAM authentication
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib64/libssl.so;/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so (found version "1.0.1e") 
-- Building Ruby bindings
-- Building Python bindings
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so (found version "2.7.5") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /bin/python (found version "2.7.5") 
-- Found PythonLibs...
-- Building Python...
-- Found Perl: /bin/perl (found version "5.16.3") 
-- Building Perl bindings
-- Found Java: /bin/java (found version "1.7.0.71") 
-- Found JNI: /usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so

-- Building Java bindings
-- Found SWIG: /usr/local/bin/swig (found version "3.0.3") 
-- SWIG 3.0.3 found at /usr/local/bin/swig
-- Python executable: /bin/python
-- Python lib dir: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
-- Ruby executable: /usr/local/bin/ruby
-- Ruby version: 2.2.0
-- Ruby dir: /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0
-- Ruby arch dir: /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
-- Ruby include path: /usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0
-- Java compiler: /bin/javac
-- Java runtime: /bin/java
-- Java archiver: /bin/jar
-- Java archive name: openwsman-x86_64-2.4.12.jar
-- Perl executable: /bin/perl
-- Perl core dir: /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE
-- Perl vendor arch dir: /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
-- Perl vendor lib dir: /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so (found version "7.29.0") 
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.1") 
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE

-- Looking for crypt.h
-- Looking for crypt.h - found
-- Looking for ctype.h
-- Looking for ctype.h - found
-- Looking for CUnit/Basic.h
-- Looking for CUnit/Basic.h - not found
-- Looking for dirent.h
-- Looking for dirent.h - found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for ifaddrs.h
-- Looking for ifaddrs.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for memory.h
-- Looking for memory.h - found
-- Looking for netinet/in.h
-- Looking for netinet/in.h - found
-- Looking for net/if_dl.h
-- Looking for net/if_dl.h - not found
-- Looking for net/if.h
-- Looking for net/if.h - found
-- Looking for pam/pam_appl.h
-- Looking for pam/pam_appl.h - not found
-- Looking for pam/pam_misc.h
-- Looking for pam/pam_misc.h - not found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for security/pam_appl.h
-- Looking for security/pam_appl.h - found
-- Looking for security/pam_misc.h
-- Looking for security/pam_misc.h - found
-- Looking for stdarg.h
-- Looking for stdarg.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stdlib.h
-- Looking for stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for strings.h
-- Looking for strings.h - found
-- Looking for string.h
-- Looking for string.h - found
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - found
-- Looking for sys/select.h
-- Looking for sys/select.h - found
-- Looking for sys/sendfile.h
-- Looking for sys/sendfile.h - found
-- Looking for sys/signal.h
-- Looking for sys/signal.h - found
-- Looking for sys/socket.h
-- Looking for sys/socket.h - found
-- Looking for sys/sockio.h
-- Looking for sys/sockio.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for vararg.h
-- Looking for vararg.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - found
-- Looking for getifaddrs
-- Looking for getifaddrs - found
-- Looking for alloca
-- Looking for alloca - not found
-- Looking for alloca.h
-- Looking for alloca.h - found
-- Looking for bcopy
-- Looking for bcopy - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of in_addr_t
-- Check size of in_addr_t - failed
-- Check type in_addr_t as HAVE_IN_ADDR_T
-- Check type in_port_t as HAVE_IN_PORT_T
-- Check type sa_family_t as HAVE_SA_FAMILY_T
-- Check type int as HAVE_INT
-- Check type long as HAVE_LONG
-- Check type long long as HAVE_LONG_LONG
-- Check type short as HAVE_SHORT
-- Performing Test HAVE_SA_LEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_SA_LEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_IPV6
-- Performing Test HAVE_IPV6 - Success
-- SSL_LIB is at >libssl.so.1.0.1e<
-- Package file openwsman-2.4.12
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/openwsman-2.4.12/build
```

And these are the results of the make command I ran afterwards.

```
Scanning dependencies of target wsman_curl_client_transport
[ 1%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman_curl_client_transport.dir/wsman-client-transport.o
[ 2%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman_curl_client_transport.dir/wsman-curl-client-transport.o
Linking C shared library libwsman_curl_client_transport.so
[ 2%] Built target wsman_curl_client_transport
Scanning dependencies of target wsman_client
[ 2%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman_client.dir/wsman-client.o
Linking C shared library libwsman_client.so
[ 2%] Built target wsman_client
Scanning dependencies of target wsman
[ 2%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/buf.o
[ 3%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/log.o
[ 4%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/memory.o
[ 5%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/misc.o
[ 6%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/uri.o
[ 7%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/uuid.o
[ 8%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/lock.o
[ 9%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/md5.o
[ 10%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/strings.o
[ 10%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/list.o
[ 11%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/hash.o
[ 12%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/base64.o
[ 13%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/iniparser.o
[ 14%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/debug.o
[ 15%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/uerr.o
[ 16%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/uoption.o
[ 17%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/gettimeofday.o
[ 18%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/syslog.o
[ 18%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/pthreadx_win32.o
[ 19%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/u/os.o
[ 20%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-libxml2-binding.o
[ 21%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-xml.o
[ 22%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-epr.o
[ 23%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-filter.o
[ 24%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-dispatcher.o
[ 25%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-soap.o
[ 26%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-faults.o
[ 27%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-xml-serialize.o
[ 27%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-soap-envelope.o
[ 28%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-debug.o
[ 29%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-soap-message.o
[ 30%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-subscription-repository.o
[ 31%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-event-pool.o
[ 32%] Building C object src/lib/CMakeFiles/wsman.dir/wsman-cimindication-processor.o
Linking C shared library libwsman.so
[ 32%] Built target wsman
[ 33%] Generating openwsman_wrap.c
Creating wrapper code for Python ...Done.
Scanning dependencies of target pywsman
[ 34%] Building C object bindings/python/CMakeFiles/pywsman.dir/openwsman_wrap.o
[ 34%] Building C object bindings/python/CMakeFiles/pywsman.dir//openwsman.o
Linking C shared library _pywsman.so
[ 34%] Built target pywsman
[ 35%] Generating openwsman_wrap.c
Creating wrapper code for Ruby...Done.
Scanning dependencies of target rbwsman
[ 36%] Building C object bindings/ruby/CMakeFiles/rbwsman.dir/openwsman_wrap.o
[ 37%] Building C object bindings/ruby/CMakeFiles/rbwsman.dir//openwsman.o
Linking C shared library _openwsman.so
[ 37%] Built target rbwsman
Scanning dependencies of target ruby_gem
[ 38%] Generating ext
[ 39%] Generating html
Creating rdoc documentation .../bin/sh: ./rdoc2.2: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [bindings/ruby/html] Error 127
make[1]: *** [bindings/ruby/CMakeFiles/ruby_gem.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought this might be a bug or a mistake in my compiling process, I reported the issue to the developer of openwsman (Thanks Klaus Kämpf) on github and he looked into it and was able to update openwsman to ensure support for Ruby 2.2 which appears to be where the issue was. I included the github issue I posted below, which includes his response. After pulling down the latest code, I was able to successfully compile, make and install openwsman.

https://github.com/Openwsman/openwsman/issues/52